# How to select bi-directional mapped rows from a table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the MySQL table called `table`.

```
| ID     |item_code| item_name   |
| 1      | 12345   | abc         |
| 2      | 12345   | xyz         |
| 3      | 11221   | abc         |
| 4      | 19261   | www         |
| 5      | 12345   | abc         |
| 6      | 62898   | abc         |
| 7      | 92648   | xxx         |
| 8      | 45678   | xxx         | 
| 9      | 1234    | pqrs        | 
| 10     | 2345    | defg        | 
| 11     | 1234    | pqrs        |
```

I want the query which will results the below table:

```
>     |item_code | item_name   |
>     | 12345    | abc         |
>     | 12345    | xyz         |
>     | 11221    | abc         |
>     | 62898    | abc         |
>     | 92648    | xxx         |
>     | 45678    | xxx         |
```

I want the result considering of:

item_code mapped to multiple item_name.  Here item_code `12345` is mapped with `abc` and `xyz`.  item_code `1234` is mapped to `pqrs`.

item_name mapped to multiple item_code. Here item_name `abc` is mapped with three items: `12345`,`11221`,`62898`.  item_name `xxx` is mapped to `92648` and `45678`.

Here is the SQL statement I tried:

```
(select a.item_code,a.item_name from table a
  join ( select item_code
           from table 
          group by item_code
         having count(*) > 1 ) b
    on a.item_code = b.item_code)
union
(select a.item_code,a.item_name from table a
  join ( select Item_name
           from table 
          group by Item_name
         having count(*) > 1 ) b
    on a.Item_name = b.Item_name);
```

But this SQL query does not generate the bi directional mapped keys.  Can someone help me generate these bi-directional mappings?

Comment: Ok you want and you want... but what have you tried till now to get the result you want?

Comment: If you have a any query that you have tried, post it with you question. Then we can help you.

Comment: Thank you for editing your question to include your own attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.item_code, t.item_name
FROM mytable t
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT item_code, COUNT(DISTINCT item_name) num FROM mytable GROUP BY item_code) code
  ON (t.item_code = code.item_code)
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT item_name, COUNT(DISTINCT item_code) num FROM mytable GROUP BY item_name) name
  ON (t.item_name = name.item_name)
WHERE code.num > 1 OR name.num > 1
```

The subqueries used in the two `JOIN` clauses are used to attach the counts for which each item *code* or *name* is repeated.  The joined result set is filtered using the `WHERE` clause at the outermost level to include only those `DISTINCT` combinations where the *code* and/or the *name* was associated with multiple values for the opposite field.

Comment: Thanx for reply, but it is giving 1234->pqrs extra.The result table should be like if one item_code is mapped with multiple item_name and also one item_name is mapped with multiple item_code, only those rows should be displayed.The final result will be exactly what i have given above..

Comment: You probably are missing the `DISTINCT` keyword *inside* each of the `COUNT` functions, which were added in an edit very soon after the initial answer was posted.

Comment: Great answer to a very poor question, I went and radically changed the question to be 500x more clear.  In the future, consider cleaning up the clarity of the question when answering.